# How to select Week Range values in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, selenium

Currently working on selenium webdrvier. I want to know how to select the week range values drop down at a time.

Am having a drop down Period, Once i selected that  week range from the period drop down then automatically i gives the another drop downs From week and To week. In the From week i have two drop down one is to select the year and another one is to select the week range W1 etc.,

In this scenario how can i select the drop downs.

Here is my HTML tag for selecting Period drop down:

```
<select id="periodId" name="period" style="display: none;">
<option value="l4w">Last 4 Weeks</option>
<option value="l52w">Last 52 Weeks</option>
<option value="daterange">Date Range</option>
<option value="weekrange">Week Range</option>
<option selected="" value="monthrange">Month Range</option>
<option value="yeartodate">Year To Date</option>
</select>
```

And this is the HTML tag to select the From week and To week drop downs:

```
<select id="fromWeekYear" style="width:60px" name="fromWeekYear">
<option value="2010"> 2010</option>
<option value="2011"> 2011</option>
<option value="2012"> 2012</option>
<option selected="" value="2013"> 2013</option>
</select>
<select id="fromWeek" style="width:60px" name="fromWeek">
<option value="1"> W 1</option>
<option value="2"> W 2</option>
<option value="3"> W 3</option>
<option value="4"> W 4</option>
<option value="5"> W 5</option>
```

and

```
<select id="toWeekYear" style="width:60px" name="toWeekYear">
<option value="2010"> 2010</option>
<option value="2011"> 2011</option>
<option value="2012"> 2012</option>
<option selected="" value="2013"> 2013</option>
</select>
<select id="toWeek" style="width:60px" name="toWeek">
<option value="1"> W 1</option>
<option value="2"> W 2</option>
<option value="3"> W 3</option>
<option value="4"> W 4</option>
<option value="5"> W 5</option>
```

Am writing code in Java. Please anyone can give me solution for this scenario.

Comment: Please suggest me some example for this question

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your WebElement into Select Object as shown below

`Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("identifier")));`

Once this is done you can select the required value in 3 ways. Consider an HTML file like this

```
<html>
<body>
<select id = "designation">
<option value = "MD">MD</option>
<option value = "prog"> Programmer </option>
<option value = "CEO"> CEO </option>
</option>
</select>
<body>
</html>
```

Now to identify dropdown do

`Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("designation")));`

To select its option say 'Programmer' you can do

`dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Programmer ");`

or

`dropdown.selectByIndex(1);`

or

`dropdown.selectByValue("prog");`

Happy Coding :)

Comment: This thing is working fine but i want solution for the scenario which i asked